# CMake doesn't find windres.exe (MingW), CMAKE_RC_COMPILER

Tags: cmake, mingw, rc

is there any specific reason why CMake doesn't find windres.exe from MingW as the RC compiler? The MingW dir is in my PATH variable, windres.exe does exist.

I always have to set the `CMAKE_RC_COMPILER` variable by hand to windres.exe in the cmake GUI.

After googling quite a while now, I only found out that more people have this problem, but I never found any real solution...

I have the latest cmake (2.8.5).

Only thing I found was: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=4068 but the things describes there don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to edit the CMakeCache.txt

```
//RC compiler.
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=g:/dev/Rtools/MinGW/bin/windres.exe
```

(or whatever the path to your MinGW install happens to be)

Then run cmake again

Answer (score 0):

For MinGW, use `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" source-directory/`

If you have MSYS installed, use `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" source-directory/`

No plumbing needed.

Answer (score 0):

Many bug fixes have been merged into CMake related to "windres" since the 2.8.5 release.

Try using CMake 2.8.12 or later: it should work with windres "out of the box" at this point.